# Uploading image via ftp in Codename One

Tags: image, ftp, codenameone

How to upload an image via FTP in Codename One? 
I've made many researches but any one lead me to the solution.
I need to provide the hostname, username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support FTP, it isn't as commonly used within apps.

Images are uploaded using [multipart requests](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html) which is the same thing as form submit in HTTP/HTML. For that you will either need a server or a cloud service that accepts multipart requests for you.

Comment: Thank you, I used PHP to make the job for me.